# How can I POST html?

Tags: html, post

I need to send a form to PHP, but one of the fields contains HTML.

When it's in the form it's fine, and will show:

```
<input id="addNote" value="<div class="line">This is my line</div>"/>
```

However, when I POST it to the server, the HTML tags have been stripped out, so it comes through as 'This is my line'.  What do I need to do to make sure the tags don't get stripped out?

Thanks!

Comment: Encode using the escape chars.

Comment: Show your server-side script. Also, your code isn't looking like that. The invalid quoting will break your HTML code.

Comment: Coding, even HTML coding, is not for everyone. You cannot post a html tag and its content by simply using `<input>` and `<form>`.

Comment: Sounds like your PHP side is stripping out HTML tags (remove_tags), its not really an HTML thing, and has nothing to do with your submit, look at the code catching what you're throwing.

Answer (score 3):

When embedding html-in-html, you should encode the HTML metacharacters so they can't be mis-interpreted:

```
<input id="addNote" value="&lt;div class=&quot;line&quot;&gt;This is my line&lt;/div&gt;" />
```

This is especially true with `"` characters, as they'll break the form for the parser. e.g.

```
<input ... value="<div class="line" ....  />
                             ^---
```

The indicated quote will be translated as **ENDING** the `value=` portion, and `line"` being the start of some other non-standard/unknown tag attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`<input id="addNote" value="<div class="line">This is my line</div>"/>` does not work at all!

Since you're using `"` to limit the value of the input field, you have two choices:

1. Change the `"` character to `'`:
   This is my line'/>
2. Substitute the quotes (`"`) inside the value for `&quot;`:
   This is my line"/>

However, none of this matters if your PHP script deletes HTML tags...

Answer (score 0):

in your .php  file use this -

```
echo htmlentities($_POST['addNote']);
```

and in your html file use single quote.

```
<input id="addNote" name="addNote" value="<div class='line'>This is my line</div>"/>
```